# OpenCart - How to store image path on database for Banners

Tags: html, opencart

This is my first question in this great page, that I use even for work. Im trying to increase the basic functionality of Opencart by adding different Banner images in different languages.

I already implemented all the logic to display this new images, but my problem comes when I try to store this information into the database.

Basically, so far this is my logic. Store the image path for the specific language inside the Banner_image_description table on the database. Pretty much as the title for the banner is done.

For displaying the pictures I have the following code

```
              <td class="left"><div class="image"><img title="<?php echo $banner_image['banner_image_description'][$language['language_id']]['image']; ?>" src="<?php echo $banner_image['banner_image_description'][$language['language_id']]['image']; ?>" alt="" id="thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>" />
              <input type="hidden" name="banner_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][image]" value="<?php echo $banner_image['banner_image_description'][$language['language_id']]['image']; ?>" id="image<?php echo $image_row; ?>"  />
              <br />
              <a onclick="image_upload('image<?php echo $image_row; ?>', 'thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>');"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="$('#thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('src', '<?php echo $no_image; ?>'); $('#image<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('value', '');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>
          <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
```

As we can see, we have the click button to upload or select a different picture. Is here were my code stop working properly.

Checking the function we call (image_upload), i noticed it writes down on the image the following information:

```
$('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + data + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');
```

This is my real problem. We I save the banner information, it does save this new picture path to the previous logic (inside the table banner_image), but not in my desire table (banner_image_description)

I dont want anyone to solve me the specific problem, I want to learn by myself. If you have any clue what Im doing wrong or have some hint or good link I'll appreciate.

This question will open the doors to many others to develop and extend the functionality in relation with image for multiple languages

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you are trying to reach, as well as your code is only a small piece of the entire page but I think I got your problem.
Since you asked not to give you the full solution then let me point you to it.

First of all I assume that this is a part of a form so in some point you are going to submit the form via a post or get request.

Ask yourself these questions:
 1. When you post a form, how does the PHP script on the server end reads the values of the form? what specific tag in the input is the tag that correlates to the $_GET or $_PUT on the server side? Are this tags ok?
 2. Try to debug the output on the server side. Obviously something is not transferring correctly. Try to do a var_dump($_POST) or var_dump($this->request->post) and see what are the fields the form is submitting.
 3. Try to debug the javascript output.

If that doesn't help let me know or try to post more code.

Comment: Hello Yani and thanks for the Help! Well, actually I didnt understand in the first read your answer, but now I understand. As you said, and I will post afterwards as solution, was a problem with the tags. Basically I thought the name of the input didnt matter and was just as an ID tag, but no, is the one on charge to give back the info to the DB. I dont really understand how PhP post and get works, but I have an overall idea. About debugging is one of the basic tools but I dont really know how to do it with php.

Comment: As you probably understand already, POST and GET methods get the variable according the name tag (id and class tags are used for javascript, name for for forms and php). You can look at POST and GET as additional data that is submitted to the page, when GET methods are simply submitted via the URL (index.php?my_val=123 and POST methods are hidden and considered more secure.

Comment: Wow, actually this last answer really made me understand, more concretely this part " POST and GET methods get the variable according the name tag (id and class tags are used for javascript, name for for forms and php)". I will post the answer when I have time since I want to add a good one so other users can learn something from it. Thanks to this help I was able to develop an Open Cart module (free) for the Multi-Language Banner.